# Show that the function series $\sum \frac{(-1)^n}{n} \arctan(nx)$ convergent

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I am given a function series where:

$$
f(x) = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{n} \arctan(nx)
$$

I want to show that this function of series is convergent on $(0,\infty)$. I am thinking of using Weierstrass M-Test. I use the upper bound of $\arctan(nx)$:

$$
\max || arctan(nx) || \leq \frac{\pi}{2}
$$

However, the series $\sum \frac{\pi}{2n}$ is harmonic series so it diverges. I know the Weierstrass M-test theorem, but I have some problems with this exercise.

Answer (score 2):

$f$ is odd and $f(0)$ is obviously well defined. Let $x>0$, then
$$ \arctan(nx)=\frac{\pi}{2}-\arctan\left(\frac{1}{nx}\right)=\frac{\pi}{2}+\underset{n\rightarrow+\infty}{\mathcal{O}}\left(\frac{1}{n}\right) $$
Thus
$$ \frac{(-1)^n}{n}\arctan(nx)=\frac{\pi(-1)^n}{2n}+\underset{n\rightarrow+\infty}{\mathcal{O}}\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right) $$
The series $\sum \frac{\pi(-1)^n}{2n}$ converges and the series $\sum \underset{n\rightarrow+\infty}{\mathcal{O}}\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$ converges by comparaison with Riemann series. Thus $f(x)$ is well defined for $x>0$, and for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ because $f$ is odd.